# Start Rails with Backbone.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, backbone.js, rubygems

I amreading about the backbone.js and make a demo application for the CRUD operation from by goggling some links.

and see the structure of the backbone.js which initial created by installing the gem 'backbone-rails',

But here my query is like when we have normal application like without using of any .js, we have some options to check the flow of the application, like for example we can write 'exit' keyword in controller and check the methods which is calling by routes and can inspect and see all the records and parameters which fetched by model and parameters which input by user .

In using of the backbone.js, i am confusing that from where the view is coming and is there any way to see it's line by line flow means
first go to model and for query data can here we can show it in console and see what is going on.

Comment: share your link from where u learnt so i can explain that how it works because there are many ways to achieve something and btw mostly backboneJS, emberJS etc get data in JSON format and if you want to to know where are the views of JS than you can see them in app/assets/javascripts/

Answer (score 1):

For debug the backbone applications place 'debugger' in your js code and the js execution will stop there if you use chrome. In other browser I am not sure if works but in chrome I used this technique many times... And you can step line by line you can check variables and so on.

For debugging rails use these gems

```
gem 'pry'
gem 'pry-nav'
```

Then in your controller where you want to inspect the variables and the calling stack put binding.pry

Like here:

```
class UsersController <...
  def index
    binding.pry
    @users = Users.all
  end
end
```